# Categorizing in R

Tags: r

I'm using the following code to search a list of items, and classify them if they contain a word that I'm looking for.

```
 yo <- c("winter", "winter storm", "downline", "Hurricane", "c", "c")

 t = data.frame(yo)

 b <- grep("winter", t$yo)
 c <- grep("downline", t$yo)
 d <- grep("Hurricane",t$yo)

 t$y2[b] = "Winter" 
 t$y2[c] = "downline"
 t$y2[d] = "Hurricane"
```

Output:

```
        yo             y2
     winter          Winter
     winter storm    Winter
     downline        downline
     Hurricane       Hurricane
     c               Winter
     c               Winter
```

Any idea why it categorizes the last two as Winter even though the grep function wouldn't find anything matched to it?

Comment: Look at `t$y2` after the first assignment.  It's "Winter" all the way down.

Comment: That's correct, that's what I'm asking why is it t$y2 all the way down if I've indexed with b. If you run the line b <- grep("winter", t$yo) it returns 1 2, and expected that t$y2[b] = "Winter" will assign the first two values of the column to "Winter", and the rest should go unassigned I believe?

Comment: @steppermotor is it a assignment question from data science specialization course?

Comment: @PPC Not at all. I graduated undergrad about 10 years ago in ECE. I don't think we had any idea that R existed, now I use R for data analysis hence I ask these questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type `t$y2[b] = "Winter"`, the y2 column does not exist yet. But as all the columns of a data.frame must have the same size, the pattern of b `c(1,2)` is repeated three times in order to fill the column.

You can type this to see what happened:

```
t = data.frame(yo)
t$y2[b] = "Winter"
t
```

If the input is a vector containing 2 elements instead of "Winter", we can see that these two elements are repeated:

```
t = data.frame(yo)
t$y2[b] = c("Winter", "Not Winter")
t
```

If the number of rows of t is not a multiple of the index vector, R raises an error:

```
t = data.frame(yo)
t$y2[1:5] = "Winter"
t
```

A simple fix is to initialize y2 with a default value before using it:

```
t = data.frame(yo)

b <- grep("winter", t$yo)
c <- grep("downline", t$yo)
d <- grep("Hurricane",t$yo)

t$y2 = ""

t$y2[b] = "Winter" 
t$y2[c] = "downline"
t$y2[d] = "Hurricane"


        yo        y2
1       winter    Winter
2 winter storm    Winter
3     downline  downline
4    Hurricane Hurricane
5            c          
6            c
```

Comment: Thank you user1470500 for the explanation.